# The "javac.exe" file does not exist in java 8 update 251 (Oracle)

Tags: java, missing-features

I am trying to practice Java on my laptop (the tablet is VERY limited!) so have installed the recommended Oracle Java from java.com. This has installed Java 8 update 251 on my machine but I cannot make it work. If I follow the instructions, take a Java file (such as `Example.java`) and try to compile it using the command `javac Example.java`, I am met with the well-known reply:

**'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

I know that the usual claim is that there is no link to the correct directory, however there is no `javac.exe` (or bat or anything else for that matter) to link it to.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you install JDK or just JRE? You need JDK to compile java source files.

Comment: Either you downloaded the JRE (JDK is here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u251-relnotes-5972664.html) or you are not looking in the right place. It's in the `bin` directory at the top-level.

Comment: And to be able to use `javac` command while in any folder you need to add your installation folder to PATH environment variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears when classpath is not mentioned for your jdk in env variables.
You need to configure env variables and provide jdk path there.
Make JAVA_HOME variable in path, provide JDK path there and add to to the path. This was for Windows.
For Mac- you need to export the JAVA_HOME in the bash_profile
To open bach_profile = open ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Thank you. So I need the JDK (Java Development Kit) instead of the JRE? I'm new to working with Java I'm afraid.

Comment: Nope, this is nonsense. The error just says that there is no javac.exe in any path, for whatever reason. FWIW, i never permanently set JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Gyro, I just add it to my "path" in the environment variables. The JDK / JRE was the real hiccup.

Comment: @Apeksha you probably need to source it after you edit it in Linux/Mac

Comment: @HugMyster javac is part of JDK, fyi

Comment: @Silviu : I agree, but I had the JRE installed.  They don't make it clear for a beginner... :-,